# Extract .wav files from a large .tgz file and store them into array for classification

Tags: python, extract, multiclass-classification

I need to do a machine learning task in which several English words are pronounced in audio recordings. My task is to take multiple recordings as input and classify which word is pronounced in each recording.
The recordings are individual .wav files and stored together in a .tgz file. In my code I want to give the .tgz file as input, and store all the individual .wav files into a data array.
This is what I tried so far:

```
data = np.array([])
tar = tarfile.open("wav.tgz", "r:gz")
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member)
    if f is not None:
        data = np.asarray(f.read())
tar.close()
```

However, when printing the data this returns all the information as bytes, stored in an array, like so:

```
b'RIFF$}\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80>\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00data\x00}\x00\x00\xcd\xff\xce\xff\xcb\xff\xca\xff\xcb\xff\xc8\xff\xcc\xff\xce\xff\xd0\xff\xd4\xff\xd1\xff\xcc\xff\xc9\xff\xdd\xff\xe5\xff\xd7\xff\xd3\xff\xd4\xff\xdd\xff\xd9\xff\xca\xff\xd9\xff\xe4\xff\xea\xff\xf4\xff\xed\xff\xeb\xff\xec\xff\xf1\xff\xf2\xff\xe5\xff\xec\xff\xf3\xff\xe9\xff\xea\xff\xe5\xff\xe1\xff\xe4\xff\xe0\xff\xe7\xff\xef\xff\xef\xff\xf4\xff\xf4\xff\xf6\xff\xf4\xff\xe8\xff\xde\
```

This continues for a while since it is quite a big file.
Can someone help me on what the best way is to extract these files individually from the .tgz file? Also, I'm not sure what the best way is to handle the files after they are extracted, more advice on that part is also very welcome!

Comment: You will need to decode the WAV file into a series of samples after extracting it from the tarball.

Comment: You need to read the WAV files. Try this library, it reads WAV and outputs a numpy array in one go https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio . Also SciPy can do that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with [scipy.io.wavfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html)

```
import scipy

all_data = []
with tarfile.open("wav.tgz", "r:gz") as tar:
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        f = tar.extractfile(member)
        if f is not None:
            rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(f)
            all_data.append(data)
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, awesome! Can you explain furtherly how you would handle these individual arrays furtherly in the classification task? How can I use them as input for my classification task?

Comment: @DanielvandenCorput that is too broad. I have no idea what network you have in mind nor what is the exact content of the arrays, so I can't answer these points right now. Try building the network yourself first, then if you have problems post another question on StackOverflow. Also, check on google, there is plenty of example of neural networks to solve speech recognition problem. Here a couple of links: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-6-how-to-do-speech-recognition-with-deep-learning-28293c162f7a and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9FPqkuoEJ8